# Python - How do I split a string that includes an escape character as a delimiter?

Tags: python, regex, string

How do I split the following string at "\x"? I am having trouble because "\" is an escape character.

```
MyString = 'A\x92\xa4\xbf'
delim = '"\"' + 'x'
MyList = MyString.split(delim)
print(MyList)
```

Additional Details: 4192A4BF is the "low serial number" that is displayed as the serial number of an Xbee radio in the XCTU program that Digi uses to configure Xbee radios.

Using micropython on the xbee to retrieve the serial number: `serial = xbee.atcmd("SL")` returns `'A\x92\xa4\xbf'` which is as far as I can tell hex(A) followed by 92A4BF. If I split at "\x" I can extract the number to read the same as on the XTCU.

Comment: That string does not contains the backslash character or the character "x". It contains the bytes `0x92`, `0xA4` and `0xBF`. How synthetic is this example and how closely is it related to what you're *actually* dealing with?

Comment: your string has only 4 characters, \x92 counts as 1 char

Comment: I guess all the OP needed to do was convert it to raw string. I've added my answer.

Comment: @deceze I added some additional details but I don't understand why you put the question 'On Hold' and marked it as unclear because Yash Krishan understood exactly what I was asking and answered my question. Thank you Yash Krishan.

Comment: That was a very lucky *guess*. The problem your actual questions spells out is very different.

Comment: @deceze Do you care to elaborate?

Comment: Try `print('A\x92\xa4\xbf')` and `print(r'A\x92\xa4\xbf')`. Two very different strings and very different problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Convert your string to raw string by doing `r'string'`**

Try this:

```
MyString = r'A\x92\xa4\xbf'
delim = '\\' + 'x'  #OR simply: delim = '\\x'
MyList = MyString.split(delim)
print(MyList)
```

Output:

```
['A', '92', 'a4', 'bf']
```

**This technique works for any escape sequence *(let me know otherwise xD)* `\x`, just set delimiter as `\\x`.** Working sample : https://repl.it/@stupidlylogical/RawStringPython

Works because:

> Python raw string treats backslash (\) as a literal character. This is
>   useful when we want to have a string that contains backslash and don't
>   want it to be treated as an escape character.

Explanation:

> When an 'r' or 'R' prefix is present, a character following a
>   backslash is included in the string without change, and all
>   backslashes are left in the string.

More: https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals